# How to solve the error on using Flutter-TTS package?

Tags: javascript, flutter, text-to-speech

E/flutter (31135): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method speak on channel flutter_tts)
E/flutter (31135): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (31135): 
E/flutter (31135): #1      TTS.build._speak (package:dyslexic_app/pages/tts.dart:10:7)
E/flutter (31135): 
E/flutter (31135):

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the case where you have just added a new package into your code and it stopped working.

Flutter uses what are called `method channels` to communicate with native side java code.

Your package must be using some native code through a channel named `flutter_tts` and it is unable to find that native code.

To fix this,

1. Uninstall the app from your development device,
2. Rebuild the app again.